# pthreads works in CLI but not in apache server

Tags: php, apache, pthreads

pthreads recognised in CLI on Ubuntu server but doesn't work in apache2

I've installed pthreads on my Ubuntu 18.04 server using the following tutorial:

https://blog.programster.org/ubuntu16-04-compile-php-7-2-with-pthreads

When I print these lines they both return "1":

```
php -r "echo PHP_ZTS;"
php -r "print_r(class_exists('Thread'));"
```

However, when I try to use the Threaded class in php I get fatal error class not found. The php ini file states that Thread Safety is disabled.

Please someone advise me. I've been trying to fix this for hours.

Thanks

Comment: The problem I think is that there are two separate php7 installations on my server and the apache2 one is pointing to the wrong one. The version that the CLI uses is stored in /etc/php7 while the version that apache is using is stored at /etc/php/7.3. I've tried installing pthreads on the version used by apache but it hasn't work (possibly ZTS isn't enabled for that one). Anyway if  I can find a way for apache to point to the php installation in /etc/php/7.3 that might be the next step to try. How do I do this please as I can't find it online anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

PThreads can *only* work on the CLI. In the [introduction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php) on the PHP.net site for Pthreads, it's explicitly stated:

```
WARNING The pthreads extension cannot be used in a web server environment. Threading in PHP is therefore restricted to CLI-based applications only.
```

As a result, Pthreads will not operate in Apache.